# PHP JSON (decode)

Tags: php, arrays, json

how can I get "required_version" from this JSON via PHP?

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": true,
        "up_to_date": false,
        "version_is_listable": false,
        "required_version": 13576,
        "message": "Your server is out of date, please upgrade"
    }
}
```

Thank you very much,
with best Regards
Enge

Comment: use `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = <<<'__EOS__'
{
    "response": {
        "success": true,
        "up_to_date": false,
        "version_is_listable": false,
        "required_version": 13576,
        "message": "Your server is out of date, please upgrade"
    }
}
__EOS__;

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->response->required_version;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Why I Need the __EOS__?

Comment: You don't need it when the string is already present. It's just a form of string delimiter. (heredoc / nowdoc syntax)